# Changing the size of shuriken particle effects to simulate a torch flame Unity3D

Tags: unity, particles

Basically I'm trying to use the "Flame" particle effect to simulate the flame on a torch. My problem is the flame is far too big. I've been trying too figure out how to resize the flame to fit the torch, but nothing seems to work. I've adjusted all the properties, and the scale itself. But no matter what it's too big. Anybody know how I could accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Changing the scale of the object won't do anything. What you have to do is change the "Start Size" property of the particle system.

[image]

Comment: I'm using the pre-built "Flame" Particle, and it's not a particle system is the problem.

Comment: @TimothyWilliams well if it isn't a Particle System than it isn't the new shuriken system.  http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Components/comp-ParticlesLegacy.html

Comment: That's what I was thinking.

Comment: Weird, it was saying it was a new particle. either way, I tried everything and nothing worked before. I read over the link you sent and I already tried all of that.